# JavaScript: How we can call Document.evaluate method for getting result

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using below code for getting result value, but while executing it shows me an error message. (`Failed to read the 'numberValue' property from 'XPathResult': The result type is not a number.`)

Please take a look to get the value.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                    var confirmationtext = "return document.evaluate( \"//*[@id='main-content']/div/div/div/h2/strong\",  document,  null,  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,  null)";
                    var returnvalue = js.ExecuteScript(confirmationtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `STRING_TYPE`. Try `NUMBER_TYPE` if you are sure that it is always a number or `ANY_TYPE` but I would not recommend this.

Comment: Actually, I've tried with stringvalue it is working fine in chrome, but when I'm using the same in code it is showing me error message

Comment: So, how we can get a string value for the same?

Comment: Use object type in execution. Then ,convert the returned output to your required type. 

public Object executeJavascriptObject(Object script) {

        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script.toString());
    }